# Why do widgets' constructos need a Context?

Tags: java, android

I just started learning Android programming and I have a doubt. If I have an Activity and (inside it) a widget, why do I have to declare a context in the widget's constructor? Shouldn't it understand which context I am in by itself? In Java, if I create a frame, I just need to type:

```
JFrame frame = new Frame();
```

I don't understand why I need to write this in Android:

```
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
```

Comment: How would you reckon it'd do that? An object created knows nothing of its creator.

Comment: I updated my question, maybe my doubt now it's more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Context class details :

Interface to global information about an application environment. This is an abstract class whose implementation is provided by the Android system. `It allows access to application-specific resources and classes`, as well as up-calls for application-level operations such as launching activities, broadcasting and receiving intents, etc .

think your application without this `It allows access to application-specific resources` .
Now **how will you add a image inside your LinearLayout -> Child ( ImageView )** for this you need some reference , by which you can access image which is declared inside drawable folder of your project .

Edited Section :

`this` is a superset of `context` in android

( i can not say that this is accurate but i have tried to understand it like this )

`new Frame() , new LinearLayout(this)` have same representation except `this` parameter , now try to avoid the `new` keyword from your code , now we have only
`Frame() , LinearLayout(this)` .

So now you calling Two constructors `Frame() and LinearLayout(this)`

**Point to be noted** : in every constructor or in every method , there is a stack which is created automatically for method or constructor . stack is created as temp-storage 
( scope-dependend ) & in the first_position of each and every stack these is a `this` of calling function . so it doesnt matter that you are sending this or not 
for android , i think brilliant minds ( android Api's creator ) have added it (`context`) for a better user_readability , that user can understand it properly .

Comment: But why in java I can write JButton button = new JButton(); while in android programming I can't just type Button button = new Button();?

Answer (score 1):

A `View` in Android needs to retrieve certain properties from the `Resources`, such as dimensions, colors, etc. To retrieve these it needs the `Context` (e.g. `context.getResources()`).